Multiprocessing questions. Accessing scipy odeint() and global memory. How to pass more parameters to the task()
I am now calculating 15 derivatives for a gradient for a gradient descent optimizing function.   Each call to odeint() takes about 0.75 seconds so it takes a while to computer a gradient.  I am to find the parameters that minimize the sum of squared error.  The program works if I don't use multiprocessing.   The problem is that the task must call the odeint() and return a sum of squared errors and the odeint() takes a while.  I would like to speed that up
Can a task called by a ProcessPoolExecutor access global memory?   I have data ( time, control output, process value) in a file that is loaded but doesn't change after that.  I want all the tasks to be able to access that data without using shared memory techniques and calculate estimated values that match the process values..
Can a task call another subroutine?  Can it do so if the subroutine calls a scipy function like odeint()
I have looked all over the internet.  The examples are too basic.  Usually example task just takes an iterator.  I must pass an iterator and an array of parameters that I want to minimize using odeint().   From what I have seen, the map function only passes an iterator and nothing else.  From my research it looks like using the Executor.submit() allows passing many variables but I have not been able to get it to pass any of these variables to the task function.
I have tried things like partial but nothing seems to work.  Am I trying to do the impossible?  Is python multiprocessing that limited?

def t1p2(p):
    """ find the values of params that minimize the means squared error
        between the actual position and the model's estimated position
    """
    pva0 = [aActPos[0], 0.0, 0.0]       # initial position velocity and acceleration
    pva = odeint(difeq, pva0, aTime, args=(p,))
    _mse = np.square(np.subtract(aActPos,pva[:,0])).mean()
    return _mse 


from concurent.futures import processPoolExecutor

def task(f, p, i):
    """ this function computes the derivative for parameter p[i].
        This is done by taking a small step in the positive and negative direction
        to compute the cost function and then find the rate of change or derivative
        of the cost function.
    """
    _save = p[i]                    # save p[i] so it can be restored later
    p[i] += h                       # take a step in the positive direction
    fpos = f(p)                     # evaluate after taking a positive step
    p[i] = _save                    # restore p[i]
    p[i] -= h                       # take a step in the negative direction.
    fneg = f(p)                     # evaluate after taking a negative step
    p[i] = _save                    # restore cell to its original value
    grad = (fpos-fneg)/(2*h)        # calculate the gradient with P as the center value
    return grad

p is an array of 15 parameters to be 'optimized'.  f is the task() function.  I is the index of the parameter I want to find the derivative for.   How do I call task() and pass the 3 parameters?  Notice that task calls t1p2 that has the odeint() and uses an array of sample times, aTime, which is global.
I think I tried everything.   What I am hoping for is to execute the del_f  concurrently instead of serially in the for loop as show.

What OS are you using?

I am using Win11. Does it make any difference?  Can a task call a library routine like scipy.odeint()?  This means that odeint() would need to be re-entrant.  Can task use a global array?  If so then why are there multiprocessing routines to use shared memory?
All the examples are too basic.  All the documentation is not enough.
Maybe I should start with more basic question like are numpy and scipy re-entrant? While writing this I searched for the answer and it wasn't addressed.

The OS is relevant because one method of solving your problem is the fork start method, which is sadly not supported on your OS. Re-entrancy is not relevant to multiprocessing, as Python subprocesses share almost no state with the parent process.

@user1402208 I suggest you post a minimal example of what you are trying to do. Keep it as simple as possible. Did you make progress with this?
